# Webform skip page programmatically

Tags: forms, webforms

I know how to `hook_alter` a Webform build form.
I also know how to validate it using a `hook_validate`.

Is there a chance to skip a certain Webform page when some validation code results in false?

I cannot find any solution ;-(

Comment: no ideas? I searched almost everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

I has just found a solution for it. Perhaps, somebody can find more pretty realisation.

**So, first step:**
Lets your 'hook_node_view' in custom module call early than webform 'hook_node_view', you can do it through hook_module_implements_alter() something like it:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'node_view') {
    if(isset($implementations['YOUR_MODULE'])){
      $group = $implementations[YOUR_MODULE];
      unset($implementations[YOUR_MODULE]);
      $implementations = array_merge(array(YOUR_MODULE => $group), $implementations);
    }
  }
}
```

**Second step:**
Remove unnecessary webform components from node object.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
  if (isset($node->webform['components']) && YOUR_CONDITION) {
    foreach ($node->webform['components'] as $key => $component) {
      if ($component['page_num'] == 2) {
        unset($node->webform['components'][$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```